# Read a file in binary mode with c

Tags: c, io, binary

I have an executable file called re.exe, I want to read its content in the binary form and then show that content in the console. I write the following code but it doesn't show the content of the binary file in the console. What's the problem?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

void readFile(const char *fileName) {
    FILE *file;
    file = fopen(fileName, "rb");
    if (file != NULL) {
        char ch;
        while ((ch = fgetc(file)) != EOF) {
            if (isprint(ch)) {
                printf("%x", ch);
            }
            else {
                printf("%02x", ch);
                if (ch == '\n') {
                    fputs("\n", stdout);
                }
            }
        }
     fclose(file);
    }
}

int main() {

    readFile("re.exe");

    return 0x0;
}
```

Comment: What is showing on the console after you run your program? Are you sure `fopen` does not fail and return `NULL`?

Comment: Is your program trying to read itself?

Comment: @purplepsycho No, It's going to read re.exe.

Comment: @s7amuser After running the program, It shows 4d5affffff90000300000004000000 in the console.

Comment: Why do you think it is not OK? Maybe these are the contents of the `re.exe` file. Use `printf("%02x ", ch);` to see the individual bytes. Also, you can use [hexdump](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_hexdump.htm) or [xxd](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xxd) to dump the contents of the file and compare to what your program is printing.

Comment: re.exe is a 20kb file. I think it's content must be more than what my program shows.

Comment: So the problem might be that you implicitly cast the return value of `fgetc` to a `char`. Try defining `ch` as an `int` instead.

Comment: @s7amuser post that as answer

Comment: Read: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgetc Look at the return value.

Comment: Okay thank you. It works now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the implicit casting of the return value of [`fgetc`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgetc/) from `int` to `char`.

Since `EOF` is defined as `(-1)` (at least in [glibc](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;f=libio/stdio.h;hb=HEAD#l136)), the returned `char` (which is by default signed in GCC) is converted to an `int` (with sign extension) as specified in section 6.3.1.8 of the [C99 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf):

> If both operands have the same type, then no further conversion is needed.
>
> Otherwise, if both operands have signed integer types or both have unsigned
>     integer types, the operand with the type of lesser integer conversion rank   is converted to the type of the operand with greater rank.

As a result, the character `0xff` is converted to `0xffffffff` and is actually equal to the value of `EOF` which causes the loop to end prematurely before reading all the file.

In addition, when printing the character with `printf("%x", ch)` or `printf("%02x", ch)`, the character is again converted to an `int` (see [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/)) and thus you can see for example the output `0xffffff90` for the character `0x90`.

In summary, the solution is defining `ch` to be an `int` instead of a `char`.